# Mongo Java Connectivity - Only Insert once

Tags: spring-mvc

I have a Mongo - Java MVC Spring 4 connectivity. My insert operations work only once, they don't do a second insert in the collection. What could be the problem?

Here's my code.

```
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.Document;

@Document(collection="subject")
public class Employee  {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    private int id;

    private String name;

    private String email;

    private String address;

    private String telephone;

    strong text
```

...

```
public class EmployeeDAOImpl implements EmployeeDAO {

    MongoTemplate mongoTemplate;

    public MongoTemplate getMongoTemplate() {


        return mongoTemplate;
    }

    public void setMongoTemplate(MongoTemplate mongoTemplate) {
        this.mongoTemplate = mongoTemplate;
    }

    @Override
    public void addEmployee(Employee employee) {

        mongoTemplate.save(employee);;
    }

    @Override
    public List<Employee> getAllEmployees() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return mongoTemplate.findAll(Employee.class);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE) annotation is for JPA and not for Mongo.

Make sure that you import the @Id from the mongo package and ID should be auto generated by Mongo.

The first insert works because int has default value of 0 and the second time it tries to insert with the same key.

if you want to have custom ids generated, here is a great tutorial for that: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-mongodb-auto-generated-field